# Force the use of interface instead of concrete implementation in declaration (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, inheritance, access-modifiers

In C++, you can do the following:

```
class base_class
{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class derived_class : public base_class
{
private:
    virtual void do_something()
    {
        std::cout << "do_something() called";
    }
};
```

The `derived_class` overrides the method `do_something()` and makes it `private`. The effect is, that the only way to call this method is like this:

```
base_class *object = new derived_class();
object->do_something();
```

If you declare the object as of type `derived_class`, you can't call the method because it's private:

```
derived_class *object = new derived_class();
object->do_something(); 
// --> error C2248: '::derived_class::do_something' : cannot access private member declared in class '::derived_class'
```

I think this is quite nice, because if you create an abstract class that is used as an interface, you can make sure that nobody accidentally declares a field as the concrete type, but always uses the interface class.

Since in C# / .NET in general, you aren't allowed to narrow the access from `public` to `private` when overriding a method, is there a way to achieve a similar effect here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you explicitly implement an interface, this will at least encourage people to use the interface type in the declaration.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
}

class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
    void IMyInterface.MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

One will only see MyMethod after casting the instance to `IMyInterface`. If the declaration uses the interface type, there is no casting needed in subsequent uses.

[MSDN page on explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28VS.71%29.aspx) (thanks Luke, saves me a few seconds^^)

```
IMyInterface instance = new MyImplementation();
instance.MyMethod();

MyImplementation instance2 = new MyImplementation();
instance2.MyMethod();  // Won't compile with an explicit implementation
((IMyInterface)instance2).MyMethod();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in the .Net world too, using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx)

As an example, [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) implements [`IBindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx), but you have to cast it to `IBindingList` to see the method.

Comment: It's known as Explicit Interface Implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the link, I was struggling to find it :)

Answer (score 2):

You *are* able to decrease a method's availability by marking it as `new`.

The example from [MSDN's CA2222: Do not decrease inherited member visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182332%28VS.100%29.aspx):

```
using System;
namespace UsageLibrary
{
    public class ABaseType
    {
        public void BasePublicMethod(int argument1) {}
    }
    public class ADerivedType:ABaseType
    {
        // Violates rule: DoNotDecreaseInheritedMemberVisibility.
        // The compiler returns an error if this is overridden instead of new.
        private new void BasePublicMethod(int argument1){}       
    }
}
```

This is really more interesting as an academic exercise; if your code is truly dependent on not being able to call `BasePublicMethod` on `ADerivedType`, that's a warning sign of a dubious design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this strategy, should it be implemented, is that the method is not truly private.  If you were to upcast a reference to `base_class`, then the method is now public.  Since it's a virtual method, user code will execute `derived_class::do_something()` eventhough it's marked as private.

Comment: In this scenario, this isn't seen as a bug, but as a feature.